# Find limit $\lim_{x\to0}(x^{-2}-x^{-4})$

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\to0}(x^{-2}-x^{-4})$$

If you consider that $x^{-4}$ approaches $\infty$ faster, then the answer appears to be $-\infty$ which is what my answer sheet indicates. However, Symbolab [gives the answer as 0](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/limit-calculator/%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto%5Cinfty%20%7D%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%5E%7B2%7D%7D-%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%5E%7B4%7D%7D%5Cright)). Which answer is correct and why?

(Sorry for another boring limits question; I often get stuck when self-studying so please accept this apology.)

**Edit:** Oh god, sorry for this becoming another "find the typo" question. I will not post another one of these questions unless I have painstakingly checked for any possible error on my side.

Comment: you calculated another limit in symbolab, and the answer for $x \to 0$ is, in fact, $-\infty$

Comment: Your answer is correct. In Symbolab, you entered in the limit as $x$ approaches $\infty$

Comment: @Jane, when your comment resolves the asker's entire confusion, you should post it as an answer, even though it is short.

Comment: Ditto to @Hrhm.

Comment: @HenningMakholm next time for sure :)

Comment: Using only Latex in the title makes the question impossible to open on some devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we have $$\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x^4}=\frac{x^2-1}{x^4}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\lim_{x\to 0}(x^{-2}-x^{-4})=\lim_{x\to 0}x^{-2}(1-x^{-2})=(+\infty)(-\infty)=-\infty.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Your symbolab link shows a computation of the limit for $x\to\infty$, which is indeed $0$.

For $x\to 0$, your own result of $-\infty$ is correct.